# How can I optimize the structure of my classes

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, optimization, multiple-inheritance

I am struggling to define the structure of my classes

I created a list of the object of the class `ObjMetaClass`. Which contains some meta-information about its object `points` (`points`: a property of the `ObjMetaClass` class).
But `points` can be of two types, one `TwoPointsPattern` class and the other two `ThreePointsPattern` class

My concern is that whenever I want to access any item, I first need to check which item is stored in the current item for casting (is it `TwoPointsPattern` or`ThreePointsPattern`)

```cs
List<ObjMetaClass> objList = new List<ObjMetaClass>();
// some items
objList.Add(new ObjMetaClass(new TwoPointsPattern(...), isTwoPointsPattern:true, rate:124));
objList.Add(new ObjMetaClass(new ThreePointsPattern(...), isTwoPointsPattern:false, rate:654));

// access items from list
for (int i = 0; i < objList.Count; i++)
{
    // check for casting object
    if(objList[i].isTwoPointsPattern)
        TwoPointsPattern temp = objList[i].points as TwoPointsPattern;
        /* some logic or function call */
    else
        ThreePointsPattern temp = objList[i].points as ThreePointsPattern;
        /* some logic or function call */
}
```

Is there a better way to improve it or avoid `if` checks? Any suggestions, please

**Structures of classes**
ObjMetaClass

```cs
public class ObjMetaClass
{
    public object points { get; internal set; }
    public bool isTwoPointsPattern { get; internal set; }
    internal int rate { get; set; }

    public ObjMetaClass(object points, bool isTwoPointsPattern, int rate)
    {
        // check expected type of points object
        if (points.GetType() != typeof(TwoPointsPattern) &&
            points.GetType() != typeof(ThreePointsPattern))
            throw new ArgumentException("Expected types TwoPointsPattern and ThreePointsPattern");

        this.points = points;
        this.isTwoPointsPattern = isTwoPointsPattern;
        this.rate = rate;
    }
}
```

TwoPointsPattern and ThreePointsPattern

```cs
public class TwoPointsPattern
{
    public double FirstDate { get; internal set; }
    public double FirstPrice { get; internal set; }

    public double SecondDate { get; internal set; }
    public double SecondPrice { get; internal set; }

    public TwoPointsPattern(double FirstDate, double FirstPrice, double SecondDate, double SecondPrice)
    {
        this.FirstDate = FirstDate;     this.FirstPrice = FirstPrice;
        this.SecondDate = SecondDate;   this.SecondPrice = SecondPrice;
    }
}

public class ThreePointsPattern
{
    public double FirstDate { get; internal set; }
    public double FirstPrice { get; internal set; }

    public double SecondDate { get; internal set; }
    public double SecondPrice { get; internal set; }

    public double ThirdDate { get; internal set; }
    public double ThirdPrice { get; internal set; }

    public ThreePointsPattern(double FirstDate, double FirstPrice, double SecondDate, double SecondPrice,
                              double ThirdDate, double ThirdPrice)
    {
        this.FirstDate = FirstDate;     this.FirstPrice = FirstPrice;
        this.SecondDate = SecondDate;   this.SecondPrice = SecondPrice;
        this.ThirdDate = ThirdDate;     this.ThirdPrice = ThirdPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code to abstraction, not to implementation. What is the logic or function call in `/* some logic or function call */` ? If this logic can be abstracted (GetAveragePrice(), GetMaxPriceAndDate(), GetMinPriceDate etc.) then you can have a PricePattern base class and instead of having to test against that property (or by type checking) you can just call these base methods without even knowing the actual type of the class

Comment: @OguzOzgul they both have different flow of logic. for different type. i can not abstract all logic

Comment: You need to share those flow of logic for us to see if there is anything that can be done. Ok, at least don't check on a property, check on the type. Currently, since there are only two types, a boolean `isTwoPointsPattern` is sufficient to discriminate between your two types. What if a FourPointsPattern is introduced later? You can at least do: `if(objList[i].GetType() == typeof(TwoPointsPattern))`

Comment: @OguzOzgul thank you for suggestion. i  am not sharing this flow logic. otherwise it will be more complex question. i am trying Miamy 's answer i think it will work

Comment: Yes, it will. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First approach - inheritance:**

```
public class TwoPointsPattern
{
  public double FirstDate { get; internal set; }
  public double FirstPrice { get; internal set; }

  public double SecondDate { get; internal set; }
  public double SecondPrice { get; internal set; }

  public TwoPointsPattern(double FirstDate, double FirstPrice, double SecondDate, 
    double SecondPrice)
  {
      this.FirstDate = FirstDate;     this.FirstPrice = FirstPrice;
      this.SecondDate = SecondDate;   this.SecondPrice = SecondPrice;
  }

  public virtual void DoSomeLogic()
  {...}
}

public class ThreePointsPattern : TwoPointsPattern
{
   public double ThirdDate { get; internal set; }
   public double ThirdPrice { get; internal set; }

   public ThreePointsPattern(double FirstDate, double FirstPrice,
             double SecondDate, double SecondPrice,  double ThirdDate, double ThirdPrice) 
           : base(FirstDate, FirstPrice, SecondDate, SecondPrice) 
   {
      this.ThirdDate = ThirdDate;     this.ThirdPrice = ThirdPrice;
   }

   public override void DoSomeLogic()
   {...}
}

public class ObjMetaClass
{
   public TwoPointsPattern points { get; internal set; }
   ...
 }

// access items from list
for (int i = 0; i < objList.Count; i++)
{
   objList[i].points.DoSomeLogic();
}
```

**Second approach - interfaces:**

```
public interface ISomeLogic
{
   void DoSomeLogic();
}

public class TwoPointsPattern : ISomeLogic
{
   public void DoSomeLogic();
}

public class ThreePointsPattern : ISomeLogic
{
   public void DoSomeLogic();
}

public class ObjMetaClass
{
    public ISomeLogic points { get; internal set; }
    ...
}

// access items from list
for (int i = 0; i < objList.Count; i++)
{
    objList[i].points.DoSomeLogic();
}
```

From the code you shown looks like `ThreePointsPattern` can be a child for the `TwoPointsPattern` so 1st approach would be better, if I didn't miss anything.

Comment: thanks, yes `ThreePointsPattern` can be a child for the `TwoPointsPattern`